# Bootstrap 4.4.1 Card carousel does not work

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a bootstrap (v4.4.1 latest version) card carousel with the help of existing Codepen. However, when the bootstrap version switched from 4 to 4.4.1 the carousel does not work as expected. When the width of the viewport is more than 768px carousel must have 3 items per slide. But when the version is switched to 4.4.1 it only has one card at a time and also the slide transition is broke. I have been trying for so long to fix this issue. and I need help to fix this issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myCarousel").on("slide.bs.carousel", function(e) {
    var $e = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var idx = $e.index();
    var itemsPerSlide = 3;
    var totalItems = $(".carousel-item").length;

    if (idx >= totalItems - (itemsPerSlide - 1)) {
      var it = itemsPerSlide - (totalItems - idx);
      for (var i = 0; i < it; i++) {
        // append slides to end
        if (e.direction == "left") {
          $(".carousel-item").eq(i).appendTo(".carousel-inner");
        } else {
          $(".carousel-item").eq(0).appendTo($(this).find(".carousel-inner"));
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* show 3 items */
  .carousel-inner .active,
  .carousel-inner .active+.carousel-item,
  .carousel-inner .active+.carousel-item+.carousel-item {
    display: block;
  }
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left),
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left)+.carousel-item,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left)+.carousel-item+.carousel-item {
    transition: none;
  }
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
    position: relative;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  .carousel-inner .active.carousel-item+.carousel-item+.carousel-item+.carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -33.3333%;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  /* left or forward direction */
  .active.carousel-item-left+.carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left+.carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left+.carousel-item+.carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left+.carousel-item+.carousel-item+.carousel-item {
    position: relative;
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  /* farthest right hidden item must be abso position for animations */
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  /* right or prev direction */
  .active.carousel-item-right+.carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right+.carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right+.carousel-item+.carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right+.carousel-item+.carousel-item+.carousel-item {
    position: relative;
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1 class="text-center mb-3">Bootstrap Multi-Card Carousel</h1>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto">
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4 active">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f44242/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 1</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/418cf4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 2</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/3ed846/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 3</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/42ebf4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 4</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f49b41/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 5</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f4f141/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 6</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/8e41f4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 7</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Code Pen Link](https://codepen.io/divya31/pen/LYEmEwE)

[My version with Bootstrap 4.4.1](https://jsfiddle.net/hr3uogxn/)

Comment: This is made with 4.0.0 https://jsfiddle.net/bilelh/o3zxabf4/ and this with 4.1.0 https://jsfiddle.net/bilelh/paf621zn/ ... I don't see the difference ! Are you sure it's not something in your Css?

Comment: Codepen clone with bootstrap 4.1.0 : https://codepen.io/bilelh/pen/WNvxewE

Comment: @Bilel Apologize. It has to be the latest bootstrap version. 4.4.1

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks fine, I actually did some proofs and I had the same problem.

It seems like a problem with the version. The new version 4.4.1 has different classes. I inspected the element of the carousel and I found that the class `.carousel-item` has an additional property `margin-right: -100%`.

If you uncheck that property, then you can see that the carousel works fine just like with the version 4.0.

Let me know if you are able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its because in the newer version of Bootstrap  have property `margin-right:-100%` set for `.carousel-item` so to overcome this problem add the following code at the top of your css.

```
.carousel-item {
    margin-right: 0;
 }
```